# Java- Printing a non static variable from a different class?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am making a game and I'm currently trying to make a timer for it. I have a class with the timer in it, that outputs a string "time" (Yes a string, not an integer, so that I can have it in the format "2:30".

Originally, I made a getter for the string, went to my render method in my main class, and typed in

```
g.drawString(Timer.getTime(), 700, 40);
```

This didn't work however, because the getter is not static.

To solve this, I made a separate render method in the Timer class, and then called it under the main render method. I.e

```
Timer time = new Timer();
time.render(g);
```

This only gave me an error.

```
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
```

Any Ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks so much!

EDIT: g is graphics.

EDIT: Error message begins with "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException: String is null" and cycles for as long as the app is running.

EDIT: The Timer class is being run every second by another class for timing purposes that I called "start." Could this be the issue?

EDIT: I am 1 week new to programming, so if there is any more necessary info needed, comment below.

Comment: 1) You're not showing the complete error message including the most important part at the beginning. 2) You're not telling us the important details of your problem. Please tell us all that we need to know to understand what's going on, what `g` is for instance, but tell us and show us even more than that. We're getting less than half the story right now.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're getting a NullPointerException, and I'm also guessing that you're using the wrong Timer object to call your method on, either that or a bad (?)Graphics object, but again will await your completion of your question.

Comment: You make a good point. Sorry. I didn't know how much of the code to put in (I have 9 classes), So i put in as little as possible.

g is for graphics as in
             public void paint(Graphics g){

the error message is super long, I will post a little more in the next comment

Comment: Thank you for that information, but again, please flesh out your question, please show the complete error message, please tell more of the details before your question gets closed.  You will want to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24712827/edit) and add this information for us.

Comment: The error message doesn't fit (2000 chars) but it starts with
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException: String is null

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24712827/edit) and add at least the first 10 lines of the error message. You must understand that the first line, the one with the NullPointerException is **the most important line** of the exception message, and your question is still missing it. It tells you which line is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

> g.drawString(Timer.getTime(), 700, 40);

The issue here I suspect is that you are attempting to use the Timer **class** and not the instance **timer**

```
Timer time = new Timer();
g.drawString(time.getTime(), 700, 40);
```

Should work as you expect.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels **user3465651's** *answer* doesn't answer **OP's** `question`

Comment: @GingerHead: I know, but given the information as presented, I'm not sure how any of us can answer the question without making SWAGs.

Comment: Thanks for the input user3465651.
Unfortunately, I get the exact same error using this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but given the current state of your question, we can only make SWAGs in attempts to try to help you. Again I ask, beg, implore you to try to improve your question, to try to provide us with more relevant information that can help us to better understand your question and help you solve it.

Key with NullPointerExceptions are the first few lines of the exception, which for some reason you still have not shown us. These lines will tell you **exactly** where in your code the exception is being thrown, and you will need to identify this line for us.

As for my SWAG, I'm guessing that you've got an active Timer object out there somewhere running in your program, and that you're trying to display the state of it, the value of its time, in another view or GUI class, but are getting stuch due to your using the wrong Timer instance in your GUI class. If so, be sure to pass the correct Timer instance into your GUI, which can be done via a constructor parameter or getter method:

```
public class MyGuiClass extends JPanel {
   private Timer myTimer;

   public MyGuiClass(Timer myTimer) {
      this.myTimer = myTimer;
   }

   //.... now you can use the actual Timer instance
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawString(myTimer.getTime(), 700, 40);
   }
```

Other possible causes of your problem -- the GUI is not being notified properly when the Timer class's state has been changed (but who knows).

Note that if this were my program, I wouldn't draw the Timer's String in a painting method but rather would simply display it in a JLabel -- much easier. Also, if Timer is one of your classes, you're going to want to re-name it so as not to confuse it with java.util.Timer or javax.swing.Timer.

Comment: Hi, sorry that my question is still not specific enough.
The JLabel idea sounds good except I'm not using a JFrame for my game, Is this an issue? I thought you can only add JLabel to JFrame.
Thanks

Comment: @user3780342: I'm not sure where you got that information from, but please unlearn it as it's wrong. A JLabel extends from Component, and so it can be added to anything that extends from Container, including JPanels, JFrames, JApplets, JTabbedPanes,...

Comment: What about applets? (not JApplets)

Comment: @user3780342: ah, you mean an Applet, which is an AWT container. You should avoid using AWT components and instead stick with Swing components such as JApplets, JFrames, JPanels, JLabels, JButtons, etc...

Comment: Ok, I will remember that in future.